# On iOS, what is the best way to set up a subview if we really would like to do initWithCenterAndSize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

For example, if we are to draw a 100 x 100 pixel circle on the main view which covers up the whole screen on the iPad, then instead of using `initWithFrame` like following 2 steps in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UINodeView *nodeView = [[UINodeView alloc] initWithFrame:
                               CGRectMake(x, y, NSNodeWidth, NSNodeHeight)];
nodeView.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

because `x` and `y` is more elegantly as `self.view.bounds.size.width / 2` to horizontally center the circle, instead of `self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - NSNodeWidth / 2`.  Is `init` by a frame first, and then reset the center a good way, or is there a better way, if there is a `initWithCenterAndSize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a fine way of doing it :)

I would have gone for generating the positioned frame first to avoid the extra method call but that's just a matter of personal preference :)

If you're using this alot in your app you could make a category on UIView that implements this (warning, untested code :)

```
- (id)initWithCenter:(CGPoint)point size:(CGSize)size {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(point.x-size.width/2,
                              point.y-size.height/2, 
                              size.width,
                              size.height);
    return [self initWithFrame:frame];
}
```

Comment: that looks good... top-left coordinate + size has a one-to-one mapping to center + size either way, right?  and center is relative to the parent, just like the top-left coordinate, and center is totally unrelated to nodeView's bounds (origin or size)... also maybe it can make sense if iOS has this method built in as well because it is just an alternative

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

```
UINodeView *nodeView = [[UINodeView alloc] initWithFrame:
                           CGRectMake(0, 0, NSNodeWidth, NSNodeHeight)];
nodeView.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

It looks nice and clear.

Comment: you mean, use `0` for x and y the first time because they get changed anyways...?